# Как разбить строку на слова и записать в масив

Tags: c

Не могу разобраться как разбить строку на слова и сохранить в массив как отдельные слова в языке Си. 
Пробую через strtok, но  к сожалению отделает только первое слово.

upd. Получаю от пользователя строку и записываю в массив

Пример:

input = cd ..

argc[0] = cd

argc[1] = ..

Вот код:

```
char split(char *commadnForSpilt) { //FIX to strtok
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (commadnForSpilt, " ");
    char *array[3];

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);


}
```

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strtok прочитайте хотя бы это.

Comment: *"Любит ли Слонопотам поросят? И **как** он их любит?"* (с) Покажите, **как** вы используете `strtok`.

Comment: Добивил сам код

Comment: А можно посмотреть вызов `split`?

Comment: Вот:   scanf("%s",&line);    
          split(line);

Comment: Если `line` это массив `char`, то нужно передать просто `line`, а не `&line`. `scanf("%s", line);` прочитает только одно слово. Используйте `fgets`

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает

Answer (score 1):

Ну ведь миллионы описаний работы с этой функцией.

```
   // Разделители
   char sep [10]=” ,.!;”;
   // Переменная, в которую будут заноситься начальные адреса частей
   // строки str
   char *istr;

   // Выделение первой части строки
   istr = strtok (str,sep);

   // Выделение последующих частей
   while (istr != NULL)
   {
      // Вывод очередной выделенной части
      printf (“%s\n”,istr);
      // Выделение очередной части строки
      istr = strtok (NULL,sep);
   }
```

В `str` у вас должна быть исходная строка.

Comment: Соббствено с этим проблем нет, есть проблема чтобы сохранить эти слова в массив, а потом использовать

Comment: @Vadym а почему вместо вывода не поставить функцию записи?)